# How to get test_accuracy and accuracy using cross_val_score

Tags: scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am running a DTC classifier using CV = 10 . I get any of accuracy array of each of 10 fold.

```
 >>clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
 >>cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=10)
        array([1.        , 0.92307692, 1.        , 0.76923077, 1.        ,
               0.92307692, 0.69230769, 0.83333333, 0.91666667, 0.83333333])
```

I am more interested in getting test and train accuracy separately  for each 10 fold.

How his can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use `sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate` which has the return_train_score argument, you can call it as such:

`from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
cross_validate(clf, X, y, cv=10, return_train_score=True)`